# How to group data by title in Pie Chart (Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

for example I have data

```
 {
  'category': 'winter',
  'amount': 10
 },
 {
  'category': 'winter',
  'amount': 10
 },
 {
  'category': 'summer',
  'amount': 10
 },
 {
  'category': 'spring',
  'amount: 10
 },
]
```

---

working (not as expected example)

https://codepen.io/Ross-Zach/pen/eYXedBr

So I want something like this

[Pie chart that I want (**SCREENSHOT**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hljW.png)

and in legend should contains just:

> winter, summer, spring

not:

> winter, winter, summer, spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data = [
  { 'category': 'winter', 'amount': 10 },
  { 'category': 'winter', 'amount': 10 },
  { 'category': 'summer', 'amount': 10 },
  { 'category': 'spring', 'amount': 10 },
];

let aggregatedData = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let item = data[i];
  if (aggregatedData.hasOwnProperty(item. Category)) 
  {
    aggregatedData[item.category] += item. Amount;
  } 
  else 
  {
    aggregatedData[item.category] = item. Amount;
  }
}
```

- Iterate through your data array and create an object that sums the amounts for each category.
- Use the keys of this object as the labels for the pie chart.
- Use the sum amounts as the data for the pie chart.